# how to get the number of digits in a number with leading zeros

Tags: javascript

For normal numbers, like `var a = 123`, it is easy to count the number of digits (with `a.toString().length`), but what if `var a = 00123`? (assume it is still in decimal).

Comment: As far as I know, `a = 00123;` stores `123` in `a`. So you simply lose the leading zeros.

Comment: Actually, `a = 00123` stores `83` in `a`.  (It's an octal constant.)  Unless you're in strict mode, in which case it's a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems you might experience here with a possible easy solution. First entering a number value with leading zeros, will be interpreted differently than expected. Generally it wont store the number in decimal format but instead octal or some other base. If you just want to get the length of that value then you need to store it as a string.

```
var a = '00123';
console.log(a.length);
```

Just keep in mind if you dont store it as a string the number will probably not be stored as decimal.

This is a common Javascript gotcha with a simple solution:

Just specify the base, or 'radix', like so:

```
parseInt('000123',10); // 123
```

You could also use Number:

```
Number('000123'); // 123
```

Comment: With parseInt() in ECMAScript 5, strings with leading zeros will not be treated as Octal.